# How do I copy a Wordpress theme into a new Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to experiment with copying Wordpress themes from free sources like Wordpress.com, downloading the HTML, CSS and JavaScript, and then create the same theme into my own theme.

I have looked everywhere and I cannot find a guide on how to copy a Wordpress theme from a source then how to upload the contents copied onto your own theme.

It would be great if someone could give me some guidance regarding this.

Comment: Where are you copying the code from?

Comment: I'm copying the code from the website itself, inspect element.

Comment: You would need to learn how to theme in WordPress. It involves php. So instead get WordPress.org, choose a theme by WordPress and look at their code to learn or sign up with TeamTreehouse or some other place.

Comment: Please start with the WordPress Codex - Theme Development https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development